# DNN ugrade to 8.0.0 Eventviewer missing, Site Settings not working

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have recently upgraded one of our DNN portals from 7.4.2 to 8.0.0.  Unfortunately for me lots of little problems are now occurring.  For a start my Event Viewer is no longer showing up in the admin module.  If I go to Admin > Site settings I get a "The service is unavailable" message.  If I try to use the HTML module this comes up blank.  I have no idea what to do to correct these issues.  I I copy over the upgrade files again this does not resolve it.  Am I missing a Dll? Do I need to make a change in the config file?  Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I finally got the answer to this question.  I had to manually get all the extensions to install again.  You can do this by using http://www.yourdomain.com/Install/Install.aspx?mode=InstallResources.  Once this was done I got back the event viewer and the site settings was working perfectly.